# write code join same table in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, left-join

I have 2 tables

```
Table 1: farm has columns id, name, id_tech, id_manager
Table 2: User has columns: id, name
```

And I run the following statement in mysql:

```
 SELECT eco_farm.id, eco_farm.name as farmname, A.name as manager, 
       B.name as tech 
 FROM eco_farm 
 LEFT JOIN eco_user A ON A.id = eco_farm.id_manager 
 LEFT JOIN eco_user B ON B.id = eco_farm.id_tech
```

and the result is
[image]

But I do not know how to write code in laravel how to retrieve data in laravel. May you help me. thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have models set up?

Comment: Yes thank you i have fully installed, my problem is not knowing how to join the same table in laravel, but now i have done under the sandeesh instruction below. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is using the query builder.

```
$result = \DB::table('eco_farm')
    ->leftJoin('eco_user as A', 'A.id', '=', 'eco_farm.id_manager')
    ->leftJoin('eco_user as B', 'B.id', '=', 'eco_farm.id_tech')
    ->selectRaw('eco_farm.id, eco_farm.name as farmname, A.name as manager, B.name as tech')
    ->get();
```

Check the documentation for more information and examples https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries

Comment: Thank sir, i did it but need to add the AS keyword after the table we are joining ('eco_user AS A', 'A.id', '=', 'eco_farm.id_manager')

Comment: @VietorganicShrimp updated. Didn't notice that since I used your sql to create this.